# Components of Linux Desktop Environment

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, desktop-environment, display-manager, display-server

I'm fairly new to Linux and finding the whole concept of desktop environments very distorted and full of noise and confusion with no real clarity...

I'm trying to fully understand how every aspect of a desktop environment works, in order to build the perfect desktop environment for me out of everything.

After a lot of research I think I'm finally beginning to understand things a bit better but I'd appreciate it if someone could let me know whether I'm on the right track with this diagram I've created.

[image]

My understanding is that a desktop environment is built upon a window manager, which communicates directly with the display server (e.g. xorg) via (e.g. x11). So a Window Manager allows you have have various Windows placed n the screen via a GUI, but a full desktop environment comes with a lot more features. In other words a Window Manager is a very simple and much more basic version of a "Desktop" - in that it basically draws application windows, you have the right-click context menu and a couple of other things.

From here the desktop environment builds on this with things such as panel manager, for the start bar (containing notifications, system tray icons, start menu etc), along with file managers (such as File Explorer in Windows), Settings Manager (Control Panel styled software) and other GUI applications.

When you boot the PC, the first thing to happen (in terms of GUI and assuming something like Plymouth isn't installed) would be for the Display Manager to kick in, such as LightDM, which is actually more of a Login Manager, but is termed Display Manager. Once you login this starts the specified Session Manager, and the Session Manager is what is responsible for starting all these other components off.

Technically there's nothing to stop me from mixing and matching various components, such as e.g. KDE Session Manager with XFCE Desktop, but I would need the extra KDE Dependencies to do this. Is all of this correct? If this is correct, then what does the `xfdesktop` package do for instance? Is this somehow pulling everything together in the DE, or is that the job of the Window Manager?

Is there anything I'm missing from this list? It feels like there is something missing from my understanding or there is some other component I'm not yet aware of. Would really appreciate any responses.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My 2cts : If you want to progress in your understanding first forget the image you posted. Not that I mean it is wrong. Just that it **can** be misleading. If you want to understand somehing, don't be something-centric. You just cannot understand the earth and its environment in a geocentric system in which the sun the moon and pluton are represented  in a similar class of accessories.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**There isn't a correct answer to any of your four questions.**

Different desktop environments can be (and are) radically different. There is no clear-cut boundary between the components that you propose and in some cases, they aren't even separate components.

In Gnome, for example, the program that "draws the windows", the "panels" and many other things is the same binary: gnome-shell.

To make things more complicated, what you describe seems to somewhat resemble how things used to work under X11/xorg, however that's not the case for Wayland-based desktops anymore, where there isn't a "Display server".

For these and many other reasons, dependencies aside, "Mixing and matching" components isn't always possible.

Comment: Your seeming report of X11/xorg's death is premature. For example, MX Linux, the top ranked distro on distrowatch.com at the time of this comment, runs X11/xorg out of the box (i.e. as the default windowing system).

Comment: @DavidYockey. Not sure where in my answer you see anything that seems a report or an opinion. I very clearly state it's the case for "Wayland-based desktops" which has a substantial user base and is enabled by default in OP's distro if they choose Gnome.

Comment: Just clarifying that X11/xorg is still actively used, in light of your remark of "how things used to work under X11/xorg".